# React: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object at Function.keys (<anonymous>)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I am trying to process a nested object in my React component. This following code work correctly

In my DRF view, I return some data as follows

```
return Response(serializedResponse.data)
```

And process it in my React component as follows

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch("api/tryme")
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status > 400) {
          return this.setState(() => {
            return { placeholder: "Something went wrong!" };
          });
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        this.setState(() => {
          return {
            data,
            loaded: true
          };
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    let matches = this.state.data;
    console.log("allMatches : " + typeof(matches));
    Object.keys(this.state.data).map(k => {
            console.log("Key is : " + k);
            console.log("Value is : " + this.state.data[k]);
          })
    return(
      <Container fluid>
        <strong>Nested object iteration placeholder</strong>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}
```

This gives me a neat console response as

```
allMatches : object
Key is : match1
Value is : [object Object]
Key is : match2
Value is : [object Object]
```

However if I change my return statement in view to follows

```
return Response({"allMatches" : serializedResponse.data})
```

and the React code to following

```
  let matches = this.state.data;
    console.log("allMatches : " + typeof(matches));
    Object.keys(this.state.data.allMatches).map(k => {
            console.log("Key is : " + k);
            console.log("Value is : " + this.state.data.allMatches[k]);
          })
    return(
      <Container fluid>
        <strong>Start </strong>
      </Container>
    )
```

I get an error in the subject line. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First way to debug and get a proper solution,

1. ensure when setting your state in your constructor should look like below; to avoid undefined issues.

   `this.state={data: {}, placeholder:''}`
2. After, look into your console log/print, once the object undefined error is gone and see the new way the data is formatted, you never can tell, it can be this.state.data.data

Comment: That solved it. My original data was an array. The second form was an object. I changed "data: [ ]" to "data: {}" in this.setState() call and it worked.

Comment: Glad I could help :)